# naming uploaded image after username?

Tags: image, security, upload, permissions

I am developing using CodeIgniter framework.

I have an image upload folder which permission is set to 755. My host is using suPHP so site users are able to upload to it.

I just noticed that when user uploads an image, the IMAGE file permission is 666.

I am naming the images using usernames so it would be quite easy for someone to guess that someone with username ‘hello’ would have an image stored in that directory named ‘hello.jpg’ or ‘hello.png’

Is this unsafe? Could a malicious visitor do something like erase or replace a member’s image from that image upload directory?

Do I have to name the image something random and then store that random image name into that user’s db table row so I know which image name matches which user?

Comment: Well, what would be the consequences if one can guess another user’s image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always validate any user input of course, but you could in this case simply check that the current user's username matches the name being used as the filename (assuming you authenticate the users prior to allowing them to upload), and ensure they have no means to specify the filename via anything they input.

In short, authenticate, and name your files using known user info', server-side data only.

Comment: I am simply RENAMING whatever image they upload to their username.

So you are saying that as long as the user is logged in and authenticated, the scenario I described above is safe?

I ONLY display the image upload form to someone that is logged in and then I rename the image from whatever they named it on their computer to their username.

Since I use usernames for uploaded images, it would be quite easy or someone to guess the image file name. I was afraid someone who is NOT signed in or authenticated could do someone malicious to that image since they could guess the name easily.

Comment: The only way 'someone who is not signed in or authenticated could do something malicious to that image' is if you provide a means for them do so, for example by accepting and using data they enter into a form. If you only use 'safe' information, information you already have, information linked to the user, information you already use to authenticate them, then you should have no problems. I cannot really comment on your system as a whole, but so long as you follow these practices you should be able to provide such safeguards.  Hope this helps!